# Magento 2 rest order API show duplicate sku in order item if product is configurable

Tags: magento2

I am getting Magento 2 order details by rest order API but the result is showing the same SKU in configured product order item that is creating an issue in SAP integration.

Anyone let me know how can we overwrite Magento 2 rest API code?

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to “overwrite magento 2 rest API code” because what you described is perfectly normal and expected.

In Magento orders, each configurable product creates two sales order line items due to the way that configurable product data is structured in the catalog. One line corresponds to the “parent” catalog product, and one corresponds to the specific variant “child” (simple) product. Both records contain the same SKU value but their product IDs are different.

In order to get all information about the ordered item both of those records *could be important*, however if you can get by with just the data from the simple product then you could [filter your REST request](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/performing-searches.html) like below:

```
GET <host>/rest/V1/orders/items?
    searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=order_id&
    searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=1&
    searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][field]=product_type&
    searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][value]=simple
```